# websocket - Response code was not 101: 200 - Handshake error

Tags: amazon-web-services, netbeans, websocket, tomcat7, handshake

I have my **java desktop application** running which act as a client in websocket communication.

**Server code (webservice) is deployed on tomcat on AWS.**

When i try to run code locally, both desktop application and tomcat server, it works fine.

The moment i point my desktop application to production url, deployed on tomcat on AWS, i get below exception. Even i tried creating `.exe`file using `excelsior jet`, but still same issue while running `.exe` file.

**Exception**

```
ex = (javax.websocket.DeploymentException) javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
```

**Response code was not 101: 200**

I am running on Netbeans, but it fails while calling server endpoint.

These are my libraries used for desktop application.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,

```
I was missing a port after hostname,
```

URL i was using was,

**ws://hostname/endpointname**

instead of this one

**ws://hostname:port/endpointname**

> By default if Tomcat is running on port:80, no need to provide the
>   port in url, but i changed my tomcat to 8080 port.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue, when provider blocks your IP or region.
The ansver is equal.
I've found a solution, to connect WS through HttpsProxyAgent and external HTTP proxy server.